# How do I add an int array into shared preferences?

Tags: android, arrays

I am trying to save an int array into the shared preferences.

```
int myInts[]={1,2,3,4};
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                        "Settings", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs
                        .edit();
                editor.putInt("savedints", myInts);
```

Since the putInt method does not accept int arrays, I was wondering if anyone knew another way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add only primitive values to `sharedpreference` ......

refer this doc:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Do you have a suggestion that I could do to have the same effect?

Comment: you can use Sqlite ...and if the data is not too large the u can put int array value one by one to sharedpreference as int value..

Comment: lets say I did the one by one int value. if I named my keys 1.2.3etc could I call it using a for loop like prefs.getInt(i,0)? Or are the keys always strings

Comment: you key should be String...you can do that if store the keys in constant file like this  public static final String VAR = "var"; and public static final String VAR1 = "var1"; -------now you can use for loop to add and fetch value like this:------for(int i = 1; i <= value; i++){
 String yourVarName = pref.getString(AppConstants.VAR + i, "");
}

Answer (score 11):

Consider JSON.
JSON is well integrated into Android and you can serialize any complex type of java object. In your case the following code would be suited well.

```
// write
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
    arr.put(12);
    arr.put(-6);
    prefs.edit().putString("key", arr.toString());
    prefs.edit().commit();
    // read
    try {
        arr = new JSONArray(prefs.getString("key", "[]"));
        arr.getInt(1); // -6
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: the problem with the JSON method is that I would like to change the array and there doesnt seem to be a way to do something like myInt[3]=4 because we're just stacking ints

Comment: unfortunately, yes! there is no way of doing this with the json library of the Android framework...

Answer (score 3):

You can serialize an array to `String` using `TextUtils.join(";", myInts)` and the deserialize it back using something like `TextUtils. SimpleStringSplitter` or implement your own `TextUtils.StringSplitter`.

Answer (score 0):

If your integers are unique, perhaps you can use `putStringSet` (see [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29)). Otherwise you have to resort to serializing / formatting your integer array as String, as suggested by other answers.