# Array that doesnt gets clear from memory when closing application

Tags: java, android

I need to have an `int` array which holds several `Integer` values. This array should not be clear when the user terminates the application. What I am going to use this for:

1. Check the last item of this array
2. if the last item in this array is 6, add 7 to the next item in the array

The array cannot be deleted after the user exits the application, I need this for generating a "subset" of a Unique ID.

So far I've tried using a `SQLite` database for holding this information, but I think this is to complex way to do it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: read up about SharedPreferences! It has been asked many time here so you will probably find solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use shared preference which is preferably a less complexion. But the problem is that you can't store a array object. Only primitive types can be stored.

But still here is  a example which uses JsonArray to do the same. But it is not a advisory one to do though,.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
arr.put(12);
arr.put(-6);
prefs.edit().putString("key", arr.toString());
prefs.edit().commit();
// read
try {
    arr = new JSONArray(prefs.getString("key", "{}"));
    arr.getInt(1); // -6
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Taken form [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7202017/603744)

Comment: This will throw an Exception saying: JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Answer (score 2):

Try serializing the array and storing it in a File. (you can use your own logic or use some other custom library like `GSON` for this purpose)
Next time when the application is launched you can take the file content
and reconstruct the array back.